# Creating an Array in Bash with Quoted Entries from Command Output

Tags: arrays, bash, stdout, quoting

I'm having trouble forming a bash array from a standard output. I've boiled it down to this minimal example:

```
~$ a=($(echo '1 2 3 "foo bar"'))
~$ echo ${a[0]}
1
~$ echo ${a[1]}
2
~$ echo ${a[2]}
3
~$ echo ${a[3]}
"foo
~$ echo ${a[4]}
bar"
```

I believe what is happening is that `"foo` and `bar"` are considered separate items in the standard output, but the goal would be to consolidate those items into one for the array.

Obviously, I could write a small loop to consolidate these terms into one, but I'm wondering of there is a more elegant solution?

**EDIT**: What goes in place of `echo '1 2 3 "foo bar"'` in my code is fairly convoluted, but the point is that **I need to form an array from some unknown standard output of this form**.

Comment: This is not going to happen without a serious kludge or two. Would you be okay with changing the output format? If you had each array entry on a separate line, that'd be a lot easier.

Comment: `eval a=($(echo '1 2 3 "foo bar"'))`

Comment: You can't do it without `eval` which is dangerous unless you can absolutely guarantee what your input will be (as it is a giant security hole otherwise).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`xargs` recognizes quotes so

```
mapfile -t a <<<"$(echo '1 2 3  "foo bar"' | xargs -n 1)"
printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}"
1
2
3
foo bar
```

Comment: Simply GREAT! +10 if i could :)

Comment: Very nice - had no idea that **`xargs` recognizes quoted tokens embedded in a string literal (works with both single and double quotes)**. For bash 3.x users (e.g., on OSX): `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra a <<<"$(echo '1 2 3  "foo bar"' | xargs -n 1)"`.

Comment: `mapfile` bash 4+ only. Otherwise -- FAB

Comment: Is there a reason to use the `<<<` form (or the `< <(command)` process substitution based form) rather than the simpler (reduced nested punctuation and reduced execution complexity), subshell-free approach of `echo '1 2 3  "foo bar"' | xargs -n 1 | mapfile -t a`? I can see the `<<<`/`< <()` forms as being an alternative for when you want the definition of the variable on the left, command on the right, but the effect should be identical, right?

Comment: Never mind, answered my own question. I thought `echo '1 2 3 "foo bar"' | xargs -n 1 | mapfile -t a` worked but it was only failing and leaving `a` unchanged; I guess `mapfile` must be backed by real file system file (which `<<<` and `< <()` provide, with my system creating temp files for both `<<<` and `<()` that are then mapped onto fd 0, though the `< <()` obscures it with `ls -l /proc/#####/fd` showing it as a pipe, not a file, due to piping from it).

Answer (score 4):

The process substitution is not only unnecessary, it is directly harmful.  You want

```
a=(1 2 3 "foo bar")
```

If you know how many items to expect, you can do

```
read a b c d <<<$(echo '1 2 3 "foo bar"')
```

Eventually, I guess you can't escape `eval`.

Comment: I understand how this would make an array with the correct terms, but what goes in place of the `echo '1 2 3 "foo bar"'` is the output of a much more complex command. I'm not sure that this solves the issue, as I need to create an array from the standard output.

Comment: To give some context, now that the OP has clarified his intent:
(a) The first snippet works only for creating arrays with a _known number of elements_ (from literals or element-specific expansions).
(b) The 2nd snippet works only if there's _1_ quoted token _at the end_ of the captured output (and that token will have its leading and trailing whitespace trimmed).
(c) [1_CR's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28902380/45375) answer provides a _generic solution_ based on `xarg`'s ability to recognize quoted tokens inside string literals.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the

> some unknown standard output of this form

into **lines** and read the lines into array by the `mapfile` command.

For example, this can be done by perl and it's core module like:

```
some_command() { echo '1 2 3 "foo bar"'; }

echo "output from some_command"
some_command

echo
echo "Parsed into array"
mapfile -t array < <(some_command | perl -MText::ParseWords -lnE 'say for shellwords($_)')
printf '=%s=\n' "${array[@]}"
```

what prints

```
output from some_command
1 2 3 "foo bar"

Parsed into array
=1=
=2=
=3=
=foo bar=
```

EDIT: Just recognised 1_CR's answer.

```
mapfile -t array < <(some_command | xargs -n 1)
```

is much better ;)