# creating an array in bash from a column in a file

Tags: arrays, bash

this is my file

```
$ cat head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter.csv
"Rec_Open_Date"|"MSISDN"|"IMEI"|"Data_Volume_Bytes"|"Device_Manufacturer"|"Device_Model"|"Product_Description"|"Data_Volume_MB"
"2016-07-17"|"686"|"630"|"618320"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone S A1530"|"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"|"0.589676"
"2016-07-17"|"560"|"570"|"42841779"|"Motorola Mobility LLC, a Lenovo Company"|"Moto X 2nd Generation, X112360445"|"$39.95 Plan"|"40.8571"
"2016-07-17"|"811"|"340"|"2465082"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-G900I"|"$69.95 Plan"|"2.35089"
"2016-07-17"|"785"|"610"|"41498628"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 6S Plus A1687"|"$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB"|"39.5762"
"2016-07-17"|"908"|"310"|"6497563"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung GT-I9195"|"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"|"6.19656"
"2016-07-17"|"919"|"610"|"0"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-G925I"|"$19 CO COMBO - NOT RECURRENT"|"0"
"2016-07-17"|"356"|"290"|"33189681"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 6S A1688"|"$39.95 Plan"|"31.6521"
"2016-07-17"|"009"|"160"|"30340"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-J500Y"|"PREPAY PLUS - $1 - #33"|"0.0289345"
"2016-07-17"|"574"|"400"|"549067"|"HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd"|"HUAWEI Y6"|"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"|"0.523631"
```

I want to store the output from this in an array

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR>1{print $7}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter.csv | sort | uniq
"$19 CO COMBO - NOT RECURRENT"
"$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB"
"$39.95 Plan"
"$69.95 Plan"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"PREPAY PLUS - $1 - #33"
```

the way I do this is write it to a log file

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR>1{print $7}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter.csv | sort | uniq > logfile
$ cat logfile
"$19 CO COMBO - NOT RECURRENT"
"$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB"
"$39.95 Plan"
"$69.95 Plan"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"PREPAY PLUS - $1 - #33"
```

and then store this in an array

```
$ u_vals=(`cat "logfile"`)
```

prning all the elements in the array

```
$ echo "${u_vals[@]}"
"$19 CO COMBO - NOT RECURRENT" "$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB" "$39.95 Plan" "$69.95 Plan" "PREPAY PLUS - $0 -" "PREPAY PLUS - $1 - #33"
```

print the 1st element

```
$ echo "${u_vals[0]}"
"$19
```

get the length of the array (zero is the first array)

```
$ echo "${#u_vals[@]}"
25
```

print the last element

```
$ echo "${u_vals[24]}"
#33"
```

**I have a 2 fold question really 

Firstly**

**what I want is create my array in one command, if possible like this, with out having to write to a file**

```
$ u_vals=(`awk -F'|' 'NR>1{print $7}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter.csv | sort | uniq`)
```

**and secondly, and more importantly, I want the array to have 6 elements, as below, but the spaces seems to be the issue**

```
$ cat -n logfile
     1  "$19 CO COMBO - NOT RECURRENT"
     2  "$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB"
     3  "$39.95 Plan"
     4  "$69.95 Plan"
     5  "PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
     6  "PREPAY PLUS - $1 - #33"

 ## this will loop through the array but sperrates the elements by spaces 
for elem in "${u_vals[@]}"; do  echo "$elem"; done
```

---

### EDIT1

**this answers my first question but not the second part**

```
$ u_vals=($(awk -F'|' 'NR>1{print $7}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter.csv | sort | uniq))

$ echo "${u_vals[@]}"
"$19 CO COMBO - NOT RECURRENT" "$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB" "$39.95 Plan" "$69.95 Plan" "PREPAY PLUS - $0 -" "PREPAY PLUS - $1 - #33"

$ echo "${u_vals[0]}"
"$19
```

---

### EDIT2

Based on answer below this is the way I chose to do it, note I use `awk` instead of the `while` posted below. Not sure which is best, but I just like and understand awk better.

```
$ mapfile -t u_vals <<<"$(awk -F'|' 'NR>1{print $7}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter.csv | sort | uniq)"


$ declare -p u_vals
declare -a u_vals='([0]="\"\$19 CO COMBO - NOT RECURRENT\"" [1]="\"\$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB\"" [2]="\"\$39.95 Plan\"" [3]="\"\$69.95 Plan\"" [4]="\"PREPAY PLUS - \$0 -\"" [5]="\"PREPAY PLUS - \$1 - #33\"")'


$ for elem in "${u_vals[@]}"; do  echo "$elem"; done
"$19 CO COMBO - NOT RECURRENT"
"$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB"
"$39.95 Plan"
"$69.95 Plan"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"PREPAY PLUS - $1 - #33"


$ printf "%s\n" "${u_vals[@]}"
"$19 CO COMBO - NOT RECURRENT"
"$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB"
"$39.95 Plan"
"$69.95 Plan"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"PREPAY PLUS - $1 - #33"
```

Comment: [this- creating-an-array-in-bash-with-quoted-entries-from-command-output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901513/creating-an-array-in-bash-with-quoted-entries-from-command-output) might be what I am looking for

Comment: `foo=( $(...) )` is not actually a best-practices way to create an array -- lots of bugs. `echo "${u_vals[@]}"` **looks** like it works, but it doesn't, actually; use `declare -p u_vals` to see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using BASH you can use `mapfile` with `process substitution`:

```
mapfile -t u_vals < <(
   p=1; while IFS='|' read -ra arr; do (( p )) && p=0 || echo "${arr[6]}"; done < file.csv|
   sort -u)
```

Test output:

```
printf "%s\n" "${u_vals[@]}"

"$19 CO COMBO - NOT RECURRENT"
"$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB"
"$39.95 Plan"
"$69.95 Plan"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"PREPAY PLUS - $1 - #33"
```

`while loop` inside process substitution is doing this:

1. Discarding first header row
2. Splitting each column using pipe as delimiter
3. Extracting only column # 7
4. Sorting and taking uniques only

[**Code Demo**](http://ideone.com/BKrTUj)

Comment: tks, out of curiosity is your `while` any better than my `awk` for any reason?

Comment: Awk can also be used instead of inner while loop. This might be tad faster as it is not invoking any external utility.